# Syncfusion Blazor grid custom column filtering error

Tags: razor, server, blazor, syncfusion

I want to have different filter settings on three grid columns. The first column has Menu filtering, the second column has FilterBar filtering, and the third column has Excel filtering.

```
<SfGrid DataSource="@Employees" AllowFiltering="true">
<GridColumns>
    <GridColumn Field="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" FilterSettings="@(new FilterSettings() { Type = Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.Menu })"></GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" FilterSettings="@(new FilterSettings() { Type = Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.FilterBar })"></GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field="@nameof(childRecord.TEIDS_ID)" HeaderText="ID" FilterSettings="@(new FilterSettings() { Type = Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.Excel })"></GridColumn>
</GridColumns>
```

The Blazor web application shows all three of the columns with the same filtering option: FilterBar. I would like to fix this discrepancy.

[image: FilterBar grid]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the filter type applies to the entire grid and since you have not defined a `<GridFilterSettings>` it's just using the default: filter bar. I've found Syncfusion to be very responsive when submitting a support ticket or posting on their forums (I'm pretty sure they don't monitor SO, but I could be wrong). You might have better luck pursuing one of those two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **`<GridFilterSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.Menu"></GridFilterSettings>`** or use either of Excel/CheckBox in place of Menu, except for FilterBar.

They apparently do not allow mixing of FilterBar with other filter types according to [this](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/170151/mixing-filterbar-filter-with-other-filter-types?reply=Sod4ur).